# How is this subset of primes different from others in the set?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

An experiment with the equation $\quad |2x^2-y^2|=z$ where $x\in\mathbb{N}, y=(2n-1),n\in\mathbb{N}\quad $ yields the number $1$ or prime numbers but not all of them. In the subset values under $100$, $z\in\{1,7,17,23,31,41,47,71,73,79,89,97\}$ but never, for example, $2, 3,5,11,13,29...$.

What do the numbers in this subset have in common that is different from the other primes? I've tried differences, mod'ing, and that's about all I can think of to try. Any ideas?

Comment: These are the primes that split in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft I'm not very advanced in abstract algebra. Can you explain the ring and its splitting in more detail, perhaps as an answer I can upvote?

Comment: I am not sure it does that much to answer the question. It is just the fact that if the prime $p$ can be written as $|2x^2 - y^2|$ then in the mentioned ring we have $p = \pm (y + x\sqrt{2})(y - x\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Why are the other primes excluded?

Comment: Because if a prime $p$ splits, then it must split into factors of the form $y \pm x\sqrt{2}$ where $|2x^2 - y^2| = p$. But as I said, this does not necessarily give a satisfactory answer, only a reformulation of the question.

Comment: The stuff I mentioned above is fairly basic stuff in introductory abstract algebra and ring theory. More generally, it starts towards the field of algebraic number theory, which is a large parts deals with how primes split in certain types of extensions of the integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than $2$ itself, your list is the primes $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8.$ Furthermore, as the form class number is one and there are integer solutions to $u^2 - 2 v^2 = -1,$ we can prove that $x^2 - 2 y^2$ does integrally represent all such primes.

Comment: Why are the other primes excluded?

Comment: @poetasis because squares are $0,1,4 \pmod 8.$